# Centralized function to access ViewData in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'd like to display some things differently, depending on the privileges the user has. To have a list of all the privileges of the current session's user, I've put them into the `ViewData`.

For now, I've created a function (`HasPrivilege`) in MainMenu.cshtml to check if a specific privilege is in the list or not. This information is used to display the tiles differently.

```
@functions {
    public bool HasPrivilege(Type privilege)
    {
        string name = privilege.Name;
        if (name.EndsWith("Attribute"))
        {
            name = name.Substring(0, name.Length - "Attribute".Length);
        }

        return ((ISet<string>)ViewData[ViewDataKeys.Privileges]).Contains(name);
    }
}

@helper RenderTile(string targetUrl, string imageUrl, string title, bool isDouble = false, string bgColor = "Gray", bool enabled = true)
{
    string linkTitle = enabled ? "" : " title=\"" + Resources.Resources.PromptNotAuthorized + "\"";
    string linkCss = enabled ? "" : " disabled";
    <a href="@(enabled ? targetUrl : "#")" class="tile @(isDouble ? "double " : "")bg-succest@(bgColor)@(linkCss)"@Html.Raw(linkTitle)>
        <div class="tile-content icon">
            <img src="@imageUrl">
        </div>
        <div class="tile-status">
            <span class="name">@title</span>
        </div>
    </a>
}

@RenderTile(Url.Action(null, "User"), "../Images/User.png", Resources.Resources.NavUsers, true, enabled : HasPrivilege(typeof(UserViewReadAttribute)))
@RenderTile(Url.Action(null, "SapXslt"), "../Images/document_gear.png", Resources.Resources.NavXSLTs, enabled : HasPrivilege(typeof(SapXsltViewReadAttribute)))
@RenderTile(Url.Action(null, "Requirements"), "../Images/clipboard_checks.png", Resources.Resources.NavRequirements, enabled : HasPrivilege(typeof(RequirementViewReadAttribute)))
```

The problem I have is: I'd like to have this functionality on every page without code duplication. Since I am lazy, I do not want to submit the ViewData into the function, it should be available from the context.

Any ideas on how to do this?

I found some posts suggesting to put the code into App_Code. But which code? Do I have to extend a class? If so, which one?

Best regards,
   Carsten

Comment: Code like this does not belong in a view - it belongs in a controller.

Comment: So you are telling me to contact the controller whenever I'd like to check if an element should be shown or not? Doubt it.

FYI: The controller IS checking the privileges quite nicely with some privilege objects.

Back to the original question: Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes. Put the code in the controller! If you think this should go in a view, then you have a major deign problem.

Comment: I've extended my original post to show the usage of the method `HasPrivilege`. If you still think this is the wrong way to go: What would be - in your opinion - the correct way to change the interface depending on the user's privileges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can centralize `@helper` functions by putting them into a new cshtml file that resides in the `App_Code` directory of MVC. They then can be called with `<CSHTML FIle Name>.Method`, e.g. if you put your `@helper RenderTile` into a file called RenderHelpers.cshtml, you can call `RenderHelpers.RenderTile(...)`

Another way to centralize code is to write extension methods, e.g. for ViewData:

```
public static class ViewDataExtensions {

    public static bool HasPrivilege(this ViewDataDictionary viewData, Type privilege) {
       // ...
    }
}
```

And then use it like this `if(ViewData.HasPrivilege(typeof(someAttribute)) {/* ... */}`

But I would recommend introducing a ViewModel for the tiles, which has a property `IsAuthorized` that is set by the controller and used to decide whether it will be rendered enabled or disabled. Then you can render a tile using the View (or DisplayTemplate) for this ViewModel, instead of an @helper function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint on how to call a method in `App_Code`! I've posted my solution below. You are right, a ViewModel would be way cleaner. But a simple boolean is more suitable for me since I need this information in other places as well, like Kendo's Grids (set editable to true or false).

Comment: I forgot to ask: Any ideas on how to prevent the additional parameter for the `ViewData`? It would be great if this information would be available in the function without providing it.

Comment: As noted above, if you write an extension method, you call this method on the ViewData instead of passing it as parameter. But in one way or another you will need access to the ViewData.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Georg here is the final solution.

The calls in `MainMenu.cshtml`:

```
@RenderTile(Url.Action(null, "User"), "../Images/User.png", Resources.Resources.NavUsers, true, enabled : Functions.HasPrivilege(ViewData, typeof(UserViewReadAttribute)))
@RenderTile(Url.Action(null, "SapXslt"), "../Images/document_gear.png", Resources.Resources.NavXSLTs, enabled : Functions.HasPrivilege(ViewData, typeof(SapXsltViewReadAttribute)))
@RenderTile(Url.Action(null, "Requirements"), "../Images/clipboard_checks.png", Resources.Resources.NavRequirements, enabled : Functions.HasPrivilege(ViewData, typeof(RequirementViewReadAttribute)))
```

The file `Functions.cshtml` in `App_Code`:

```
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using System.Web.Mvc;
@using TestcaseRepository.Controllers;

@functions {
    public static bool HasPrivilege(ViewDataDictionary<dynamic> privileges, Type privilege)
    {
        string name = privilege.Name;
        if (name.EndsWith("Attribute"))
        {
            name = name.Substring(0, name.Length - "Attribute".Length);
        }

        return ((ISet<string>)privileges[ViewDataKeys.Privileges]).Contains(name);
    }
}
```